# Creating a function over multiple lines - Javascript Challenge

Tags: javascript, function

I'm attempting to create a function over multiple lines. Parameters of the challenge: function returns 'barbarian' and only 2 characters per line. I keep trying to use a fat arrow to declare my function, but fat arrows don't seem to work if you don't have them connected.

My current work:

```
f=
(
)=>

'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n\
s\
'
```

This works, but the ')=>' is 3 characters long. I really just want to know how it is possible to even stretch out the creation of a function. I can't find any info on it anywhere as it's obviously not very practical.

Comment: Seems like a better match for [codegolf.se] than [so]...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a **practical**, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Comment: @JoKing Fair enough. The OP probably should have read the [help] on both sites...

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

https://jsfiddle.net/wwr66653/5/

```
The code is too big to post, see fiddle
```

This was done using http://www.jsfuck.com/ It's not practical but neither is the question

Answer (score 1):

You might use `constructor` of any built-in method e.g. of `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
f=
[]
[
'\
m\
a\
p'
][
'\
c\
o\
n\
s\
t\
r\
u\
c\
t\
o\
r'
](
"\
r\
e\
t\
u\
r\
n\
'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n\
s\
'"
)
console.log(f())
```